# ExtJS MVC defer control until grid is loaded

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a textbox and a grid in ExtJS 4.0.7. I'd like to input something in the textbox and update the grid on change. Using this snippet in the controller

```
init : function() {
    this.control({
        'filter' : {
            change : function(current, previous, eOpts) {
                console.log(this.getMyGrid());
            }
        }
```

My grid is not yet defined when the change event first fires. How can I work around that -- ideally I'd like to load the 'filter' textfield last?

Answer (score 0):

One can work on the store directly, and any changes to the store will be visible in the grid as well. So instead of getting the grid, the trick is to work on the store directly:

```
this.getStore('GridDataStore')
```